# Can’t delete orphaned migration files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I just want to simply start everything over from my rails application in terms of the database and migration files, but it seems to be giving me some issues. I have some orphaned migration files and figured the easiest way to resolve this is just simply to reset everything, but when I execute `rake db:drop`, I can see that there are some “Up” migration files, which makes no sense to me:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:~/myapp]# rake db:drop
[root:7e2d33988106:~/myapp]# rake db:migrate:status

database:                                                                                                                       

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name                                                            
--------------------------------------------------                                                                  
   up     20190407090433  Create XXX                                                               
   up     20190410030059  Create XXXXXXXXX
   up     20190410175712  Create XXXXXX                                   
   up     20190410182100  Create XXXXXX                              
   up     20190415074848  Create XXXXXX                                                                             
   up     20190415083044  Create XXXXXX                                                                                              
   up     20190417190704  Create XXXXXX                                                                         
   up     20190522183047  Create XXXXXX                                                      
   up     20190522183048  Create XXXXXX                                                                
   up     20190612191730  Create XXXXXX                                                                                   
   up     20190612191731  Create XXXXXX                                                                             
   up     20190625054859  Devise XXXXXX                                                                  
   up     20190625060209  Add fieXXXXXX                                                       
   up     20190625060842  Create XXXXXX                                                         
   up     20190625064307  Create XXXXXX                                                                             
   up     20190625064719  Create XXXXXX                                                                                              
   up     20190625065252  Create XXXXXX                                                                         
   up     20190625065605  Create XXXXXX                                                      
   up     20190625070851  Create XXXXXX                                                                
   up     20190625071050  Create XXXXXX                                                                                   
   up     20190625072222  Create XXXXXX                                                                             
   up     20190625125714  Create XXXXXX                                                                  
   up     20190627084009  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                    
   up     20190627131148  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                          
   up     20190628121627  Add confirmable to devise                                                                                                               
   up     20190628123312  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                          
   up     20190629070450  Add fkey project contact                                                                        
   up     20190701114647  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                  
   up     20190702091825  Remove XXX
   up     20190704050933  Delete XXX                                                                                                
   up     20190705072626  Change XXX                                                                                                   
   up     20190706053250  Create XXX                                                                                          
   up     20190710100441  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                          
   up     20190711055440  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                                       
   up     20190712091957  Add fkey to evidence                                                                                                   
   up     20190712110757  Create active storage tablesactive storage                                                            
   up     20190715120458  ********** NO FILE **********                                                                      
   up     20190716064144  Make XXX                                                                                   
   up     20190717040139  Change fkey raw detail                        
   up     20190718081613  Make severity enum                                                                                                              
  down    20190719041739  Remove XXX                                                                                          
  down    20190722052137  Change XXX
  down    20190722100749  Create XXX
  down    20190722123346  Create XXX
  down    20190722123426  Create XXX
  down    20190722123520  Create XXX
```

I don’t understand. How do I simply just start over? I thought `rake db:drop` did that? I can’t do a `rake db:migrate:reset` or `rake db:reset` because I get errors about tables not being found… so I just want to start over.

**EDIT**

I have even logged into postgresql manually and dropped the database, but yet the migration statuses still show Up.

I’ve tried to delete all my migration files, deleted the schema.rb, and I still cannot reset the database because of attributes missing and what not. This is freaking ridiculous and makes no sense!

Look at this:

```
[root:7e2d33988106:~/myapp]# rake db:drop                                                                                                                                                                      10:40AM/07.22
[root:7e2d33988106:~/myapp]# rake db:migrate:status                                                                                                                                                            10:40AM/07.22

database: 

 Status   Migration ID    Migration Name
--------------------------------------------------
   up     20190407090433  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190410030059  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190410175712  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190410182100  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190415074848  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190415083044  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190417190704  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190522183047  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190522183048  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190612191730  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190612191731  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625054859  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625060209  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625060842  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625064307  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625064719  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625065252  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625065605  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625070851  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625071050  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625072222  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190625125714  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190627084009  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190627131148  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190628121627  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190628123312  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190629070450  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190701114647  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190702091825  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190704050933  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190705072626  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190706053250  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190710100441  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190711055440  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190712091957  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190712110757  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190715120458  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190716064144  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190717040139  ********** NO FILE **********
   up     20190718081613  ********** NO FILE **********
```

How is this possible?

Comment: It does not make any sense that the migration info is there after deleting the database. I would double-check you are connected to the right database.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently after starting a project with `bigint` IDs and wanted to change everything to `uuid`. The project was still early on so a drop/reset was easier than a migration to change over to the new IDs. What fixed it for me was doing the `rake db:drop` and then manually deleting the `db/schema.rb` file and any unnecessary migration files I no longer needed before trying to recreate the database using `db:setup`.

If the `db/schema.rb` file remains, I believe it will try to recreate the database from that.

Comment: So I actually just went ahead and deleted all the migration files (they’re backed up), deleted the `db/schema.rb` file, and ran `rake db:drop` and `rake db:setup` and it’s still giving me errors about some IDs missing that used to be in some migration files. It’s almost like something is cached.

Comment: Did you make sure to stop/reset the rails server? Try `spring stop` after running the db:drop and deleting the schema.

Comment: Yeah the rails server isn’t even running right now.